# how to install a python extension for php on windows 8?

Tags: php, python, windows-8

I want to know how to install a [`python extention`](https://pecl.php.net/package/python/0.8.0) for `php` on `windows 8` ?

This `extension` allows the `Python interpreter` to be embedded inside of `PHP`, allowing for the `instantiate` and `manipulation` of `Python objects` from within `PHP`.

I found out that "The easiest way to install the Perforce extension is by using the PECL installer" : (depending on that [guide](https://github.com/jparise/php-python#installation))

```
pecl install python
```

I try to run it with my command prompt but I get this error :

> 'pecl' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un
>   programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

I found also a video in `YouTube` that shows [how to Add PECL Extensions to PHP on Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EIl6Rokp1Q&lc=z12yzx0rztmcg3w4204ccjpjutzajfpr5ig), but it wasn't useful for me because the package I downloaded has not any file that has an extension `.dll`

So please help me, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform this command you're going to need to open up the command line in order to actually be able to have your computer run this. Here is a guide on how to use command line on a windows computer so that you can input the command which they suggested.

https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-2618089

Comment: Thank you, but I already try that, & get that error :
'pecl' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.